# How do I determine why our application crashes for some people, but not others?

Tags: c#, wpf

This is a tough problem, which I'm not sure how to solve. (Hence my asking here, :) ) I'm on a team of about a half dozen developers working on a WPF app. At this stage we've got a working application. Not all of the features are in it yet, but we're making progress. Everyone on the team can run the app, except for our boss who has a problem running it. When the app first starts it brings up a start screen/landing page with some buttons. All of the rest of us when we run the app we can easily click on any of the buttons. One of these buttons is labels "Orders" and takes the user to another screen where they can work on the orders. When our boss runs it, the app always crashes. However it doesn't do this at all for me, nor any of the other developers. This makes it really hard to figure out what's wrong because I can't duplicate it. I've got to admit that the problem might not be with WPF, but might instead be with the .NET framework, but at this point I don't know. I've got to start somewhere.

So ultimately the question is this, how do I determine what's failing on a different machine than my own? One that I don't have access to?

We're working with VS 2015, .NET Framework 4.5.2.

Comment: Does it not return a stack trace or exception information for you? That would be a start to solving the issue.

Comment: Does boss have same .NET framework? Also you could add error logging so you can just grab bosses error log and see what happens.

Comment: It's very possible that the other computer does not have either the same .NET framework or it does not have the libraries referenced in your project. Make sure you're doing a proper employment, or enable error logging to check where the error is being thrown.

Comment: Get your boss's machine to debug it, there can be all kinds of possible root cause. First step would be checking event viewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick check before you do anything else: right after a crash run Event Viewer and go to Windows Logs -> Application. You should see a number of messages related to the app and the crash including exception information that often sheds light on exactly what's going wrong.

Comment: OK, this is on me. I confess I didn't think of that. Thank you for suggesting! I showed me in which routine the error occurred. I was able to find the problem after that.

Answer (score 10):

Diagnostics and logging.

Add as much diagnostic code as you can think of (and then add some more) to the code and log it to a file or the event log or a remote database or where ever. This would include call stacks, parameter values, system information etc. Then when the application crashes you can examine these logs and determine what's different between your machine and the customer's.

Without this information you're just guessing.

Answer (score 1):

You can put some crash report controls, 
Find similar question hear [exception-reporting-from-a-wpf-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038572/exception-reporting-from-a-wpf-application)

or try something from hear : [CrashReporterdotNet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CrashReporterdotNet/) 
,
[Crash nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=crash)

Comment: Thank you for the link to that exception reporting for WPF. Very handy!

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot, but easy enough to research.  Your problem may have its root cause in hardware.  Compare the video cards of your peers and boss.  Your boss may have a card that's not within the Microsoft recommended guidelines.  In WPF, there are ways to manage rendering based on the hardware.